# How can I download, compile and execute a simple ImageMagick (++) on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, imagemagick

For no particular reason other than to learn a graphic library API I decided to give ImageMagick a try. I thought I'd be downloading a DLL along with a header file (*.h) and then create a c++ program that uses this header file and links against the DLL.

Now, the problem is: I didn't find such a header file.

I found ftp://ftp.imagemagick.org/pub/ImageMagick/binaries/ImageMagick-6.6.7-Q16-windows.zip that contains a few DLLs and EXEs, but no header file.

On the other hand, at http://image_magick.veidrodis.com/image_magick/windows/ I found a few zip files that are full of header files, but without any DLL. I could probably create such a DLL if I compiled the the tree contained in such a zip file, but since I don't know if I am going to like ImageMagick, I'd rather not do that, especially since I am on windows and the entire build process seems to be made for a Unix variant.

In short, my question probably boils down to: is there a possibility to create a *simple* ImageMagick "application" in c++ or c, and what are the minimal requirments for it, and where would I get them.

**Edit**: As per a comment, I have tried the **MagicWand C API** http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-wand.php
I can compile the c source file, but I cannot link it because of undefined references to *MagickWandGenesis, NewMagickWand, MagickReadImage, MagickGetException, MagickRelinquishMemory, MagickResetIterator, MagickResizeImage, MagickNextImage, MagickWriteImages, MagickGetException, MagickRelinquishMemory, DestroyMagickWand and MagickWandTerminus*. And it's these symbols that I thought I'd find in a DLL.

**Edit**: maybe ImageMagick is just too big for my purposes and it is not as simple as I'd like it to be. In this case, I'd be happy for any pointer towards other graphic libraries that can do a bit more than just straight lines and circles.

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-wand.php?ImageMagick=i2dun73u3svqp5lng3akiihob3

Answer (score 0):

we need to know your requirements to advise any image processing library. there're many with different capabilities: [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/), [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html), [libjpeg](http://libjpeg.sourceforge.net/), [GIL](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/gil/Generic+Image+Library) and so on.

also probably what you need is just a native Windows library like [GDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Device_Interface), [GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [DirectX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX) (Direct3D or Direct2D)